# Integral of $(\sin x)^3(\cos x)^3$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

For the **integral of (sin x)^3(cos x)^3** I got *1/6(cos x)^6 - 1/4(cos x)^4 + C*. This seemed to work but my book had  **1/4(sin x)^4 - 1/6(sin x)^6 + C.** This is similar to what I got but instead of cosine they had sine and they had the signs(+/-) switched. *So my question is: are both correct?*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to _Mathematica_.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with _Mathematica_ software.

Comment: I guess you could check by differentiating.  Or try math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: BTW, your two answers agree up a constant.

Comment: BTW.2, _Mathematica_ software gives the computationally simpler form of `-(3/64) Cos[2 x] + 1/192 Cos[6 x]` for this integral.

Comment: At least now you know. If you do ever manage to use *Mathematica*, you should still feel free to ask here; otherwise, ask at the math site.

Answer (score 2):

```
Integrate[Sin[x]^3 (Cos[x])^3, x];
Plot[{-(3/64) Cos[2 x] + 1/192 Cos[6 x], 
  1/6 (Cos[x])^6 - 1/4 (Cos[x])^4 + 1/24, 
  1/4 (Sin[x])^4 - 1/6 (Sin[x])^6 - 1/24}, {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]